# Is there a way in Python to check if the public IP was changed without external request?

Tags: python, ip, vpn

So I have a bot on Python that check some data in the cycle. There is a public IP check at the start of the code:

```
ip = get('https://api.ipify.org').text
```

I need to check if the public IP was changed by any means (e.g. VPN) in the beginning of every cycle WITHOUT external request.
Is it possible by any way?

Comment: The answer is no. Your public IP is set on a router that is almost always different than the computer your are running the check.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```py
import os
import urllib2

def check_in():
    fqn = os.uname()[1]
    ext_ip = urllib2.urlopen('http://whatismyip.org').read()
    print("Asset: %s " % fqn, "Checking in from IP#: %s " % ext_ip)
```

Comment: I assume that this expression use external request too.